# AgoraKit cannot send `userinfo` to remote users

Tags: ios, swift, agora.io

I am integrating Agora into my iOS Swift 5 app, and the basic use case reveal inexplicable behavior. Say Alice calls Bob, when Alice joins channel with userinfo specified:

```
        agoraKit.joinChannel(
            byToken: nil
          , channelId: "chan-1234"
          , info: "alice-userid"
          , uid: 0
        ) { [weak self] (sid, uid, elapsed) in
            print("\n Join channel ...: for sid: \(sid), uid: \(uid), dt: \(elapsed)")
        }
```

the `info: "alice-userid"` data cannot be accessed by Bob in:

```
    func rtcEngine(_ engine: AgoraRtcEngineKit, firstRemoteVideoDecodedOfUid uid:UInt, size:CGSize, elapsed:Int) {

        let userInfo = agoraKit.getUserInfo(byUid: uid, withError: nil)        
        print("added user: \(uid), with userinfo: \(userInfo)") // get uid, nil

    }
```

On Bob's side, `userInfo` is nil. So I tried joining with user account,

```
         agoraKit.registerLocalUserAccount("alice-userid", appId: AppID)
        agoraKit.joinChannel(
              byUserAccount: "alice-account-data"
            , token: nil
            , channelId: "chan-1234"
        ) { [weak self] (sid, uid, elapsed) in
            print("\n Join channel ...: for sid: \(sid), uid: \(uid), dt: \(elapsed)")
        }
```

This fails outright. I am referencing the docs here:

- [Building a 1-to-many iOS video app with Agora](https://www.agora.io/en/blog/building-a-one-to-many-ios-video-app-with-agora/)
- [FAQ - Strings](https://docs.agora.io/en/faq/string)

In the second case the doc has typos, and the API is out of date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose that you have already registered Alice and Bob with `registerLocalUserAccount:appId:` method. Both of them must join the channel with `joinChannelByUserAccount:token:channelId:joinSuccess:` method. Make sure that `registerLocalUserAccount:appId:` method is returning 0 which means that client was successfully registered.

Now as stated in [Agora documentation](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/oc/Classes/AgoraRtcEngineKit.html#//api/name/getUserInfoByUid:withError:) about `getUserInfoByUid:withError:` method:

> After a user joins the channel, the SDK gets the user ID and user account of the remote user, caches them in a mapping table object (AgoraUserInfo), and triggers the `didUpdatedUserInfo` callback on the local client. After receiving the `didUpdatedUserInfo` callback, you can call this method to get the user account of the user from the userInfo object by passing in the user ID.

This means that the proper timing for calling `getUserInfoByUid:withError:` is when `rtcEngine:didUpdatedUserInfo:withUid:` delegate method is called.

I'm guessing from your snippets that your class is already conforming to AgoraRtcEngineDelegate protocol. So all you have to do is to implement this delegate method and call `getUserInfoByUid:withError:` inside method body.

**EXAMPLE:**

Step 1:

Make your class conform to AgoraRtcEngineDelegate:

```swift
// Assign delegate when instantiating
lazy var agoraKit: AgoraRtcEngineKit = {
  AgoraRtcEngineKit.sharedEngine(withAppId: "YourAppID", delegate: self)
}()

// Assign delegate later
agoraKit.delegate = self
```

```swift
// Conform to AgoraRtcEngineDelegate
extension MyClass: AgoraRtcEngineDelegate {
  //...
}
```

Step 2:

Register user with `registerLocalUserAccount:appId:` method.

```swift
// User with 'bob' username will be registered
let registerResponse: Int32 = agoraKit.registerLocalUserAccount("bob", appId: "YourAppID")
if registerResponse == 0 {
    // Successfully registered
} else {
    // Failed to register
}
```

Step 3:

Join channel after user registered successfully.

```swift
agoraKit.joinChannel(byUserAccount: "bob", token: nil, channelId: "room123") { (channel, uid, elapsed) in
    print("User joined channel \(channel) with \(uid). Elapsed time is \(elapsed)ms.")
}
```

Step 4:

Implement `rtcEngine:didUpdatedUserInfo:withUid:` delegate method.

```swift
// This method will be triggered after Agora SDK
// caches user ID and user account of the remote user. 
func rtcEngine(_ engine: AgoraRtcEngineKit, didUpdatedUserInfo userInfo: AgoraUserInfo, withUid uid: UInt) {
    var error: AgoraErrorCode = .noError
    let userInfoWithUid = agoraKit.getUserInfo(byUid: uid, withError: &error)
    if error == .noError {
        // Do something with AgoraUserInfo object
    }
}
```

Comment: could you provide a code example? I 'm not quite following you. In the docs I don't even see that delegate method for swift ... (https://docs.agora.io/en/faq/string)